# Prove the set of rational expressions $K(t)$ is a simple transcendental extension of the subfield $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, proof-explanation, extension-field

Two similar questions were asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3476641/506332) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2502909/506332); but I do not find the answers satisfactory.

In Ian Stewart's *Galois Theory*:

**Theorem 5.3.** The set of rational expressions $K(t)$ is a simple transcendental extension of the subfield K of C.

**Proof**. Clearly $K(t):K$ is a simple extension, generated by $t$. If $p$ is a polynomial over $K$ such that $p(t)=0$ then $p=0$ by definition of $K(t)$, so the extension is transcendental.

My question: why is $K(t):K$ a field extension? In the text, the definition of field extension is "a monomorphism $\iota: K \to L$, where $K$ and $L$ are
subfields of $\mathbb{C}$". Now $t$ is a variable, hence $K(t)$ fails to even be a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ (just like $\{f(x)| f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$), let along a subfield. What am I missing?

Please help if you can-many thanks in advance!

Comment: Huh, does he really define it that way (requiring subfields of C)? You might check if the publisher has errata. The 1994 edition defines a field extension to simply be a monomorphism of fields.

Comment: In the early editions, Stewart does everything in full generality first; in the later editions, he does everything in the complex numbers first, then goes back and does arbitrary fields. It's a field extension because there's a monomorphism from $K$ to $K(t)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you both very much!